# Modular Inverse and Chinese Remaindering

Tags: number-theory, modules

I am given a positive integer $n$, two elements $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}^*_n$, and integers $l$ and $m$, such that $\alpha^l = \beta^m$ and $\gcd(l, m) = 1$.

How do I compute $y \in \mathbb{Z}^*_n$ such that $\alpha = y^m$ in time O(len($l$)len($m$) + (len($l$) + len($m$))len($n$)$^2$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By Bezout, $\rm\:gcd(L,M)=1\:\Rightarrow\: LJ-KM = 1\:$ for $\rm\:J,K\in \Bbb Z,\:$ therefore

$$\rm\: B^M = A^L\:\Rightarrow\ B^{MJ} =\, A^{LJ} =\, A^{1+KM} =\, A\, A^{KM}\:\Rightarrow\: A\,  =\, (B^J A^{-K})^M$$